# The notifyItemRangeInserted command isn't working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm having a problem when call the `notifyItemRangeInserted` of the adapter. When I call this method, nothing happens, simple as that. I've tried to set some `println()` in the `ViewHolderAdapter`, but he isn't called, so I can't view the prints.

I've tried all of the "notify" commands of the adapter, and none of these work. Simply nothing happens.

That's my `MainActivity`. All the objects and arrays I've tested, all of them are working like a charm. I can't understand why the notify doesn't work.

```
class MainActivity:AppCompatActivity(){

    //Declarations of the variables
    var pageNumber = 1
    var limitPerPage = 5
    lateinit var product: Product
    var productList = ArrayList<EachProduct>()
    var myAdapter  =ViewHolderAdapter(productList, productList.size)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState:Bundle?){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
        recyclerView.adapter = myAdapter
```

The code to add items on the list and notify the `ViewHolderAdapter` is

```
    //update the product list
    fun updateProductList(product:Product){
        for(i in 0 until 5 step 1){
            productList.add(product.produtos[i])
        }
        showData(productList,pageNumber*limitPerPage)//then notify
    }

    fun showData(productList:List<EachProduct>,productsListSize:Int){
        myAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(0,productList.size)
    }
```

That's my ViewHolderAdapter class

```
class ViewHolderAdapter(private var products: List<EachProduct>, private val productsListSize: Int): RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolderAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent:ViewGroup,viewType:Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_layout, parent, false)
        returnViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = productsListSize

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        holder.productName.text=products[position].nome
        Picasso.get().load(products[position].fabricante.img).into((holder.productLogo))
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        val productName:TextView=itemView.ProductName

        var productLogo:ImageView=itemView.ProductLogo
    }

}
```

I expect the `ViewHolderAdapter` to be called, but this is not occurring. Why is that happens? I can't understand. I'll be very grateful if someone could help me.

Comment: mind formatting your code first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because initial value of the variable `productsListSize` is zero. Remove it from the constructor and change adapter like this:

```
class ViewHolderAdapter(private var products: List<EachProduct>): RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolderAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun getItemCount() = products.size

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A reason can be that the initial size of the item list you want to show is 0 and the recycler view height is set to wrap content. At the moment, for this case I see 2 options:

1. Keep wrap content for recycler view and make sure the initial list size > 0.
2. Set the height of the recycler view to match_parent or a fixed size and notifyItemRangeInserted will work without issues.